# How add exception in IIS url rewrite (ASP NET Core)?

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, url-rewriting

I have rule:

```
 <rule name="main" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="main/([^.]*)/$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/main/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

References /main/xxxx/ go to /main/, but I need make rule with one reference (/main/docs/) whitch doesn`t have redirect.

Help me please make exception in rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> References /main/xxxx/ go to /main/, but I need make rule with one reference (/main/docs/) whitch doesn`t have redirect.

To achieve the requirement, you can try to [add a condition to the rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-conditions), like below.

```
<rule name="main" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="main/([^.]*)/$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="main/doc/" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/main/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```